# For a site that only allows logging in with a single 3rd party, can the 3rd party credentials be the sole credentials used for my site?

Tags: http, security, authentication, oauth

I'm writing a web app that is very tied to a different app (Twitch), so my plan is to only offer logging in through them. I'm trying to come up with an auth scheme for my app, and am thinking about implementing it by just packaging up the OAuth2 creds I get from Twitch, and setting that as a JWT cookie. [See diagram of auth design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBCVb.png)

I'm having a hard time finding another example of someone doing or suggesting this, so I get the feeling I'm missing some reason why this is a bad idea, but I can't figure out why. The cookie is a JWT so it's signed, and since the tokens are all from Twitch they can be revoked on their end if necessary. And since all the Twitch creds I need are in a cookie, I don't need to store any access tokens in my DB.

So am I missing something that makes this a bad idea, or is this a secure enough solution to use?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting question. Sadly the answer to this is "it depends", based on the risk / reward to your app and business. Let me try to clarify that to help.

Let's assume that in your system authentication is core to the service. So essentially if your users cannot authenticate then they are not able to access the system.

Using a third party to provide authentication has many pro's and con's. Obviously the pro's are around not having to manage credentials, password resets, attempted attacks on the credentials etc. Also, there are advantages to the customer of not having another set of credentials to manage.

The con's largely are around the dependancy on the third party, if Twitch goes down then no-one can use your system. (This might be true anyway, based on your description).

Essentially, what I recommend is that you weigh up the pro's and con's in your environment. Assuming that the pro's outweigh the con's then using OAuth2 is a great way of authenticating.

While I don't have an example to hand of a website using only 3rd party auth I do believe the industry is getting there. Many sites have 3rd party auth at the top of their sign in options showing a preference over creating a new set of credentials. You don't have to look much further than StackOverflow that has the following order:

1. Google
2. GitHub
3. Facebook
4. StackOverflow account